Sum of multiple piecewise function, find x so that the sum is biggest
$f_{i}(x) = \begin{cases} 
a_{i}c_{i} + b_{i}, & -0.1< x < c_{i} \\
\\
a_{i}x + b_{i}, & c_{i} \leq x \leq d_{i} \\
\\
      e_{i},& d_{i} \leq x<0.1
\end{cases}$
Known facts:

$a_{i}>0$
$a_{i}, b_{i}, c_{i}, d_{i}, e_{i}$ are all constants in each $f_{i}(x)$, it's just that each function has its own set of constants, and they can be different
$a_{i}d_{i} + b_{i} > e_{i}$, which means when $x = d_{i}$, the function reaches its max value: $a_{i}d_{i} + b_{i}$
$e_{i}$ could be bigger or smaller than $a_{i}c_{i} + b_{i}$, but both are always smaller than $a_{i}d_{i} + b_{i}$

Sum of these piecewise functions: $$S = \sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x)$$
Now how to find x so that S reaches its max value?

Each piece is on a disjoint domain, so find the max on each piece then take the max of those?
